# Unittest library keeps having problems importing module upon running tests

Tags: python, import, aws-lambda, module, python-unittest

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

The content of my files are as follows:

library.py:

```
def hello():
    return "Hello World"
```

main.py:

```
from library import hello

def main_func():
    return hello()
```

test_main.py:

```
import unittest

from src.main import main_func


class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual(main_func(), "Hello World!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Now, when I run my unittests using the following command:

> python3 -m unittest discover test

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/example/test/test_main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.main import main_func
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/example/src/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from library import hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'library'
```

Can someone please explain how I can get this to work? I am deploying functions to AWS lambda so need the import structure as it is otherwise it won't work. Is there a way to configure unittests to work with this import structure?